# PHP continually compress PNG

Tags: php

I am trying to compress a PNG file until I hit a target mark, using a dirty-ish method. But I am struggling to get any compression going. I know that at the final point, I set compression to 0, but that is because I expect the file to have been compressed.

1) Upload a png with a form

2) While the size is greater than 25000, compress it by 5 (imagepng())

I need to use the buffer to re-capture the image instead of constantly saving it (I think that's a good way). The following code isn't my production code but it's the exact method.

```
$postedImg = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$size = filesize($postedImg); // eg 35000
$info = getimagesize($postedImg);
$mime = $info['mime'];
if($mime === 'image/png') 
    $img = imagecreatefrompng($postedImg);

    while($size > 25000){
        ob_start();
        imagepng($img , NULL, 5);
        $obImgStr = ob_get_contents();
        $img = imagecreatefromstring($obImgStr);
        ob_end_clean();
        $size = filesize($obImgStr);
    }
    imagepng($img, 'image/goes/here.png', 0);
```

Comment: Compressing a compressed file typically yields no improvement, and can actually result in a _larger_ file. In any case, you can't compress any arbitrarily large image to 25k. Starting with an image, the compression algorithms will yield a resulting size. If that's larger than 25k then you're stuck.

Comment: 25000 bytes ~= 25 kb ... come on ! 25kb PNG is still a very small image. Why do you need to compress it ?

Comment: It's for a database blob, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PNG compression is **lossless**. If you compress it to 5, then to 5 again, you're going to end up with 5 still. In the same way, when you finally output your image at 0 (which would only happen if your first attempt at 5 hit the 25k), what you're actually doing is undoing any compression you just did. That's because the quality of the image is not affected at all by the compression (the doc's name for that option is misleading). It's just like a zip... all it does is reduce the file size, with the drawback that the file needs to be reinflated on the other end.

A better way of approaching this is to compress it incrementally, starting at e.g. 1, then 2, then 3 until you get the size you want. Even so, as said in the comments above, you may never get your target size.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for this explanation. I will resize the dimensions then until I hit my mark.